# Javascript date conversion is adding an hour from 0200 to 0300 on Daylight Savings Time. I want to prevent that from happening

Tags: javascript, dst

I hit a recent problem where I'm validating dates to make sure a start date is not greater than an end date. The dates entered are
start: 3/13/2022 02:30
end: 3/13/2022 03:15

When I convert these to dates in my code an extra hour is applied to the start date making it 03:30.The end date converts as expected and remained 03:30. Because of this my validation is getting hit and we see an error stating "start date cannot be greater than end date".

Am I missing something or how do I prevent this hour from being added?

I've tried changing the format of the date, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share the code you tried

Comment: Hi.  There is no time being added, but rather the clocks go from 01:59 to 03:00.  There is no 02:30 on that day.  IMHO, your validation should test this and say that the input time is *invalid*.  (Assuming you are asking about a time zone that started DST on March 13 2022, such as the in the US, Canada, and others)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your system's local timezone, to compare those two dates, have you tried to convert them to timestamp ?

Maybe you could log the dates to the console using the date.toISOString() to see what they look like when converted to utc+0